# Why is github proposing "compare & pull request" when I'm the only contributor/maintainer in the repository?

Tags: github, git-branch, pull-request

Why is github proposing "compare & pull request" (green button) when I'm the only contributor/maintainer in the repository? Like shown in this screenshot:

[image: "compare & pull request" button]

I find it strange that I should ask myself for a pull request. Shouldn't I just be able to merge the branch without asking for a pull request?

Thanks!

Comment: I saw that this button disappears overnight. Why is this only for a certain amount of time? And for how long? What are the parameters of this?

Answer (score 0):

Pull requests can still be useful for keeping track of your own work, leaving notes, and letting other developers discussion, review, and follow it.

This is all optional though, if you prefer you can just merge locally.